# Update many nested array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In below document i have to update the  "value": "7" object.How can i do that.if one array means we can use $.if we know index of the array also we can do that but in my case i cant apply more than one $ and also i don't have index info.

{

```
    "data": [
      {
          "value": "1",
      "children": [
    {
      "value": "2",
      "children": [
        {
          "value": "3",
          "children": [
            {
              "value": "4",
              "children": [
                {
                  "value": "aaa"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": "5",
      "children": [
        {
          "value": "6",
          "children": [
            {
              "value": "7",
              "children": [ // i want to update this value
                {
                  "value": "bbb"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
 }
```

Comment: Don't nest arrays. This is the wrong structure for representing trees in a database in a useful way for query or update anyway. See ['Model Tree Structures"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) in the core documentation. There is a whole section on it with various approaches. None of them are what you have done.

Comment: can you suggest tree structure for the above nested comments data

Comment: I have no idea what you want to use it for. You are better off reading the documentation and then coming back and asking a question about your actual implementation, providing details of your use case and with an udnerstanding of which methods can be applied. My "Opinion" or anyone elses should be of little consequence to **the needs of your actual application**. This **always** comes first. And not what someone else says. Learn that lesson well.